# Subset a dataframe using the characters elements of N vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I do have a dataframe with 55 columns called `df.example`. Each columns of this df possess a title, let's say "A1","A2" to "A55"

I also have 16 elements within a list called `Factor.lst` that regroup the 55 titles.

Now I would like to subset the `df.example` using the encoded titles within the 16 elements called Factor. For exemple, I tried this way :

```
F1 <- subset(df.example, select=c(get(Factor.lst)))
```

Or

```
F1 <- subset(df.example, select=c(get(Factor.lst[1:16])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 res <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern="^Factor\\d+")),
               function(x) subset(df.example, select=x))


 lapply(res, head,2)
 #$Factor1
 #  A5 A8 A32
 #1  2  5  18
 #2 12 15  10

 #$Factor2
 #  A1 A7 A52
 #1  6  7  10
 #2  5  5   9

 #$Factor3
 # A9 A13 A42
 #1 10  10  20
 #2  8   5  11
```

#### Update

If you want to do the same with `Factor.lst`

```
  Map(`[`, list(df.example), Factor.lst)
```

#### data

```
Factor1 <- paste0("A", c(5,8, 32))
Factor2 <- paste0("A", c(1, 7, 52))
Factor3 <- paste0("A", c(9, 13, 42))
Factor.lst <- list(Factor1, Factor2, Factor3)

set.seed(24)
df.example <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 55*5, replace=TRUE),
                     ncol=55, dimnames=list(NULL, paste0("A", 1:55))))
```

Comment: thanks you very much that's work perfectly. Now I will try to understand the code ;)

Comment: @ePoQ No problem.  It may be better to check the output of each single piece of code. ie. `ls(pattern="^Factor\\d+")`, then `mget(ls(pattern="^Factor\\d+"`, in that order.